# Reset stores in Reflux before each test

Tags: reactjs, jasmine, refluxjs

Is their a way to reset the stores in Reflux.

I am wanting to reset the stores in Reflux before running each test in Jasmine.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to do it yourself, since Reflux doesn't dictate how you must store data in your store, and thus there is no official interface to a stores data.

For example I do it like this:

```
function defaultState() {
    return {
        userId: -1,
        displayName: null,
        loggedIn: false
    };
}

var state = defaultState();

var userStore = Reflux.createStore({
    // all your store methods

    reset: function () {
        state = defaultState();
        // do other cleanup, or trigger a change event
    }
});
```

So in your jasmine tests you would now just have to call: `myStore.reset()`

In case you are wondering why I put `state` and `defaultState()` outside of the store: I do this because this has the advantage that nobody can mess with your stores state from the outside, only the store can change the state, but of course this is just a minor implementation detail and you are free to make everything part of the store itself.

Answer (score 0):

This example React/Reflux project configuration might be of interest too:
https://github.com/kentor/react-flux-testing/blob/master/tests.webpack.js